# Get all child, grandchild in recursive tree

Tags: php, laravel

I have this problem where i can only get the direct child of a parent right now, where i need to get all the child and grandchild from the parent data, the result should be like this

[image: Expected Result]

Here's the current code that i'm use right now

```
public function tree_view(Request $request){
    
    $data = DB::table('users')
            ->select('id', 'username', 'referral', 'name')
            ->get();

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
         
        $item = \DB::table('users')
        ->where('referral', $value->username); 
        
        $downline = $item->count(); 
        
        
        $data[$key]->downline = $downline;  # Total Downline  
    }
    
    return view('admin.tree_view', ['data'=> $data]);
}
```

and this is the database structure (all data is from same table (users))

[image]

Comment: if you use relationships then you can do without package also I feel you need to change your table structure, I would suggest using set theory

Comment: @bhucho can you explain more about set theory? and what change do you mean?

Comment: search tree structure in php using set theory there are some pdf you can read them and then change db structure accordingly will help traversing data you can even create some accessor and mutators in model to access them easily

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [this package](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset).

Read the [document](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset#readme) of this package. You can get all parents, children, ancestors, descendants. You must just add three columns to the table. And after that execute this code in `php artisan tinker` :

```
User::fixTree();
```

Then you can use the capabilities of this package.

Comment: is there another way without using a new package?

Comment: This problem needs an algorithm. Actually, this package uses a DFS algorithm. You can implement it yourself or use another algorithm. For some projects with the same problem, I've used this package.